# How far in the future does the Google Directions API take into account of current traffic conditions'

Tags: google-directions-api

I'm building a mode choice model using Car and Public Transport journey times from Google Maps, and want to see how traffic impacts Car journey times on a daily and hourly basis.

I understand that the "duration_in_traffic" parameter will return a journey time using current traffic conditions when the "departure" parameter is set to the immediate future. I also understand that when the "departure" parameter is set to the far future, e.g. next week, the "duration_in_traffic" parameter uses average traffic conditions for that time and day.

How far in advance does current traffic conditions impact the "duration_in_traffic" parameter? Is it of the order of the next few minutes, or the next few hours?